# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined when giving POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, express-jwt

I have created an entire backend for creating categories for my blog application.

Tech. Used: MongoDB, express-jwt, jwt

Different Files are:

**server.js**

```
......

// middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

// cors
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    app.use(cors({origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`}));
}

// routes middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', blogRoutes);
app.use('/api', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/api', tagRoutes);

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Listening App
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${port}`);
})
```

**caregory.js (Routes)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { create, list, read, remove } = require('../controllers/category')

// Validators
const { runValidation } = require('../validators');
const { categoryCeateValidator } = require('../validators/category');
const { requireSignin, adminMiddleware } = require('../controllers/auth');

router.post('/category', categoryCeateValidator, runValidation, requireSignin, adminMiddleware, create);
router.get('categories', list);
router.get('category/:slug', read);
router.delete('category/:slug', requireSignin, adminMiddleware, remove);


module.exports = router;
```

**category.js (controllers)**

```
const Category = require('../models/category');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const { errorHandler } = require('../helpers/dbErrorHandler');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    const {name} = req.body;
    let slug = slugify(name).toLowerCase()

    let category = new Category({name, slug});

    category.save((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            })
        }
        res.json(data);
        
    })
}

exports.list = (req, res) => {
    Category.find({}).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            });
        }
        res.json(data);
    });
};

exports.read = (req, res) => {
    const slug = req.params.slug.toLowerCase()

    Category.findOne({slug}).exec((err, category) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            });
        }
        res.json(category);
    })
}

exports.remove = (req, res) => {
    const slug = req.params.slug.toLowerCase()

    Category.findOneAndRemove({slug}).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            });
        }
        res.json({
            message: 'Category Deleted Successfully'
        });
    })
}
```

**signin function**

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    // check if user exist
    User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User with that email does not exist. Please signup.'
            });
        }
        // authenticate
        if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Email and password do not match.'
            });
        }
        // generate a token and send to client
        const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });

        res.cookie('token', token, { expiresIn: '1d' });
        const { _id, username, name, email, role } = user;
        return res.json({
            token,
            user: { _id, username, name, email, role }
        });
    });
};
```

**requireSignin Middleware**

```
exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
    userProperty: "auth" 
});
```

**authMiddleware**

```
exports.authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const authUserId = req.user._id;
    User.findById({ _id: authUserId }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User not found'
            });
        }
        req.profile = user;
        next();
    });
};
```

**adminMiddleware**

```
exports.adminMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const adminUserId = req.user._id;
    User.findById({ _id: adminUserId }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User not found'
            });
        }

        if (user.role !== 1) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Admin resource. Access denied'
            });
        }

        req.profile = user;
        next();
    });
};
```

Problem:
When I POST a request using Postman in order to make a category which is as follows:
[image: Posting the request]

Headers and other data I used:
[image: Headers info]

I get the following error:
[image: Error after POST request]

Solutions I have found online and followed:

1. Initially was using body-parser.json() and changed it to express.json() (latest versions support JSON parsing)
2. Tried both urlencoded extended: true and false.
3. Checked thoroughly my entire code for any mistakes (couldn't find any particular).
4. Checked server.js to ensure that I have defined middleware first then the routes.

Still, this issue persists and I am unable to find a solution.

I am new to backend development and I am unaware of any basic mistakes I may have committed here. I request you to help me find a solution as I am stuck here for days.

I'll be a great help if I can get this sorted out.

Thanks.

Comment: What's on line 91 of auth.js? You're probably trying to grab the `user._id` from the `req`, but if the user hasn't signed in, there's no user, which results in the type error.

Comment: Looks like you defined `userProperty` as `auth` but trying to access it via `user` property in the rest of the code. Change `userProperty` value to `user` in the `requireSignin` middleware and give it a try.

Comment: @HamzaSabljakovic Yes. It worked. Thanks a lot. If you can spare some time can you please explain more about this userProperty so that I can get to what it is used for? 
Thank You.

Comment: @lux at line 91 the `adminMiddleware` function starts. As suggested, the main issue was in `requireSignin` middleware.

Comment: Sure @ShrishSharma, simply put, it is a way to define a custom property name that holds decoded jwt value. It can be set to anything (as long you use the same name in the rest of your code). In the newer version of express jwt is called `requestProperty` https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/bc9cd6b038cb4ce7638453ade47c23e482347bd3/src/index.ts#L44.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a different error in requireSignin Middleware, if I am using the secret in back ticks then following error comes:

[enter image description here][1]

```
export const requireSignin = expressJwt

({
secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
algorithms: ["HS256"], // added later
requestProperty: "user",
});
```

And if I change my code to this:

```
export const requireSignin = expressJwt({
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
algorithms: ["HS256"], // added later
requestProperty: "user",
});
```

Then following error occurs:

[enter image description here][2]

And if I hard code my jwt secret then **no error** comes, if anyone knows how to rectify it please explain.

Comment: I am unable to see your error screenshots. Can you edit them?

Comment: The error is resolved now, I have used this statement before the requireSignin Middleware:  **dotenv.config();** 
and now it's working perfectly, thanks for replying.

Comment: That is great. Best of Luck.